# ActionBar is appearing in the first activity but not appearing the second one

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio

I have an app with three activities with the theme set to Light.DarActionBar and the first activity has action bar while the second one doesn't have it.  How can I get it to show up in the second activity?

my class Profile.java

```
public class Profile extends Activity { 
    private Button modeBtn;
    private Button increaseBtn;
    private Button decreaseBtn;
    ...
    ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
        ...
        ...
    }

    ...
    ...

    public void silentEnable(View view){
        // set the ring mode to silent
        myAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
        status.setText("Current Status: Silent Mode");
    } 
}
```

Comment: can you please post your Manifest file as well?

Comment: her it is http://mrad4apk.blogspot.com/2015/05/manifist.html

Comment: Your manifest seems OK. What is the API version you are using?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just replaced this

`public class Profile extends Activity`

with this

`public class Profile extends ActionBarActivity`

Comment: Thats not the efficient answer. Do you think that Activity doesn't have action bar ?

Answer (score 1):

I think,you have defined your app theme in your activity tag in manifest file.Define your application theme in in the application tag.

I hope this will help you.But,if you have any confusion then please upload your manifest file,So I can see it.

Answer (score 0):

If your activity extends ActionBarActivity, then add

```
getSupportActionBar().show();
```

And if your activity extends Activity, then add

```
getActionBar().show();
```

Set theme(having action bar) for application not for an activity.

Comment: where should i add this ?? under the OnCreate Method

Comment: Obviously you have to add this in OnCreate method

Answer (score 0):

You should extend AppCompatActivity. You can still use **getSupportActionBar().show()** with it

ActionBarActivity was [deprecated](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html) with update 22.1.0